# Descendants function don't return a heirarchy result

Tags: olap, mondrian

Descendants function return only a level children instead hierarchy. To eliminate my errors i used DB, Cube and query from this [tutorial](http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/07/a-simple-date-dimension-for-mondrian-cubes/). I my case i recive only month, except year-quarter-month hierarchy.

[image]

How to fix it? I use xmondrian 3.12.

Comment: where is the mdx?

Comment: @whytheq in the link. But i already found cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in shell. It show only last column.